# Inheritance in .NET is useless?

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance

I'm quite new to .NET programming. I know that .NET programming is 100% object oriented. An intriguing paragraph I read in a book about ASP.NET 4 states that

> Inheritance is less useful than you might expect. In an ordinary application, most classes use
>   containment and other relationships instead of inheritance, because inheritance can complicate life
>   needlessly without delivering many benefits. Dan Appleman, a renowned .NET programmer, once
>   described inheritance as “the coolest feature you’ll almost never use.”

I'm a little bit confused here and I need .NET programmers to tell me what should I take and what should I leave.

**Edit**

Please people understand my question, first the author didn't say literally "Inheritance in .NET is useless", that was my way to zip the hole question in some words to fit as a title. Second, the book is from Apress and its title is: "Beginning ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010" page 72.

Comment: Useless???? Say that to the designers of the Base Class Library

Comment: Which book? I want to not buy it.

Comment: You want to feel the pain of using a language that supports architecting an object by containment only? Try to use VB6

Comment: How can inheritance be useless if it's a feature you'll "almost never use"? It can only be *almost* useless then.

Comment: @Carlos: I don't understand your comment. I'm new to .NET, have you something that can help me with my question?

Comment: A strange book you read :-) Inheritance is used everywhere in .NET. The only limit in the CLR is one class can only inherit from one base class (and many interfaces). Some languages "emulate" multi inheritance (eiffel for .NET for example) though.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised to see an author describe .NET inheritance as useless.  Can you quote that paragraph for us?  Inheritance is *useful*, but it doesn't solve every problem.  Thus the need for *containment and other relationships*.

Comment: What a profoundly strange and misguided viewpoint. You might need to consider a different book if that quote is any indication of its content. What Carlos is talking about is that the entire .NET Framework uses inheritance *extensively*. The "Base Class Library" is the most fundamental classes available to all .NET languages.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that is inflammatory in a community because it goes against "the religion."  FWIW, I don't agree with the statement at all, and I think everyone else here disagrees with it as well.  My advice: Pretend that paragraph was never there and go on with your training.  You can form your own opinion later on when you have a fuller understanding about .NET, OOP, and .NET's implementation of it. Lord knows programmers can be an opinionated bunch!

Comment: are you sure you are not quoting something out of context? if no, get me the publishers. i have a book to write too. C# in more depth :)

Comment: A beginner programmer needs inheritance as much as you need a Ferrari to commute to work every day.  Pointless, unless you have that gadget that turns all the traffic lights to green.  Located between the ears in a skilled programmer.

Comment: .NET is not a programming language. Rather it is a common platform that has several languages (e.g. C#, VB.NET, F#, etc.) I think you are referring to C# in this question, so please make that question about C#, not .NET in general.

Comment: @gmagana: +1 for "...go on with your training.  You can form your own opinion later...".  @mak: You are correct that .NET is not a programming language, but the question did not state that it is.  The question is about inheritance, which is defined by the .NET platform, not by the language (for example, inheritance works essentially the same way in VB.NET and C#; inheritance relationships are expressed in IL, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch. Inheritance is not only useful, it's also a core concept, as every class inherits from System.Object (not sure if there are hacks/CLR stuff that doesn't).

Also in certain technologies like ASP.net MVC you will almost certainly use inheritance (by creating a Base Controller).

Everyone uses Inheritance all the time, most of the time without really realizing it. There is not that much inheritance in most smaller/medium sized apps, instead interfaces are often used, for example for Dependency Injection. However, pretty much every non-trivial application tends to have a base class floating around somewhere from which other classes inherit.

I'm guessing that's what the author means, the decision between defining a base class or Interfaces. Microsoft recommends base classes, but in real life Interfaces seem to be more common. Also since C# does not support multiple inheritance (A class that has more than one base class) Interfaces offer more flexibility at the cost of not being able to centralize common code or enforce certain constructors.

Comment: Good point.  I would add that you don't need to choose between base classes and interfaces.  You can use them both.  Use interfaces to define your abstractions; use base classes implementing the interfaces to centralize common code.  My team uses this approach and it is very beneficial.

Comment: Composition is NOT about implementing interfaces. Composition is, for example to have one object of certain class as a member on another class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: @Edgar Good point, when I wrote this I hadn't yet read the Design Patterns book which does describe composition as something different than I though it does. Updated answer.

Comment: "Everyone uses Inheritance all the time, most of the time without really realizing it." - which is exactly the point. "In an ordinary application...inheritance can complicate life...." Just because you use it (in a framework designed and implemented by 1% of programmers) doesn't mean you have to deeply understand it - otherwise, we'd be suggesting that beginning programmers learn the Win32 API, x86 ASM, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I think the inheritance that's presented in most intro object-oriented academic classes *is* quite useless.  You'll always see hierarchies for Animal or Shape, **but most real problems don't look like that**.

And both of these examples are broken quickly.  Take a look at Linnaeus classification of species in biology or [this article](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) about Rectangle Shape to see what I mean.  Any inheritance hierarchy will break down after a certain number of levels because leaf classes are getting further away from maintaining IS-A with the base class.

Any model represents a choice of what to leave in and what to exclude.  Inheritance can certainly work for some models and not so well for others.

Examples of where inheritance works well are data structures and interfaces.  An interface says that method signatures are inherited, leaving out implementation details.  So if you can abstract what's common to all List or Set or Map implementations you've got something that provides structure but leaves implementation details to designers.

I'd say that inheritance works quite well in those cases.

Like most blanket statements, the one that you cited isn't universally true.

Comment: +1 I couldn't have said this any better myself, so now I don't even have to try. This is a superb answer, especially the last sentence: "Like most blanket statements, the one that you cited isn't universally true."

Comment: +1; I'd just add a tip of the hat to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Although too often, the term inheritance is applied to interfaces as well as classes (or types) I believe this creates confusion and misunderstanding. Interfaces are NOT inheritance.  Inheritance of one class (or type) from another defines implementation usage, that calling a function in the instance of the derived type should execute code in the parent. Specifying that a class implement an interface is NOT inheritance, it is simply a constraint that requires that the class include those functions, properties and methods defined by the interface.

Comment: I see no evidence that anyone is confused.  The comment seems unnecessary almost six years after the fact.

Answer (score 6):

Inheritance is an OO concept, that varies very little in .NET than in any other OO language, save that .NET allows single-inheritance (for classes) only; which is also pretty common.

The author is right that *inheritance generally* is easy to use incorrectly, and that generally encapsulation is a better option, but this is not specific to .NET in any way.

There are many times when it makes perfect sense to use inheritance, and you shouldn't shy away from it; polymorphism etc being a prime example. But most standard "data in data out" code doesn't need polymorphism.

It is there, valuable - nay, *essential* (at least, to preserve sanity; you can of course avoid it if you like doing things the hard way). Feel free to ignore it or use it.

But make your own decision. Personally I think the author is being confusing and perhaps a bit short-sighted.

Answer (score 2):

Given your admitted lack of familiarity with the subject matter, and the fact that the book you're reading, well, got published, it seems most likely that you've just misunderstood the intended message. Perhaps the writing of that paragraph is not very clear. Inheritance is extremely useful and widely used.

Comment: Don't be so sure; I've seen some very terrible and I'll-informed books. I even had my name (as technical reviewer) expunged from one because they refused to make essential changes (i.e. fixing fundamental flaws in the understanding of the type system and language).

Answer (score 2):

Just as one very small example, if there were no inheritance, when you created a form in windows, or an ASP.Net WebPage in a web application, you'd have to add all the code for all the "Window" functionality (e.g. below**) yourself, and add this code into every such form or web page you created ...
  Useless ??? Hardly!

***examples of some functionality you "Inherit" from System.Windows.Form"***
(Move window around, resize it, minimize, maximize, restore it, paint the screen under it and near it, Process messages generated by mouse clicks on it, control whether or not it has the focus, pass data back and forth between it and other screen elements, etc. etc. )

Comment: This is a good way of explaining it to someone new to the paradigm. The rest of us might have gotten a little caught up in the apparent absurdity of the claim, and forgotten the experience level of the asker. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of what needs to be said here has already been said by folks with far more experience than myself. However, as one who migrated from VB6/VBA to the Endless And WOnderful World of True Inheritance available in .net, I can say that discouraging the newcomer from seeing it as an end-all solution is not necessarily a bad thing.

When I first began exploring the idea, I found all kinds of cool things to do through inheritance. But in the end, I ended up with some pretty poor code, difficult-to-maintain class hierarchies, and overall mess. It looks like an almost magical solution to the newcomer (and even MORE so to those who have endured the pain of VB6/VBA for years first). The reality is, like design patterns, inheritance is often used "because I can" instead of "because I need to".

I am betting the author intended to convey the point that inheritance, often seen as a "first-order" solution to those with less experience, should REALLY only be used when it is the proper solution. And that it is easy to think it may be a proper solution in the wrong circumstances.

It can be tempting to use inheritance as a means to make the work of coding easier. In my early days learning vb.net, I of course had some difficulties, and often, inheriting from a class which had been a struggle to create seemed like an attractive solution to the problem of creating a different flavor of that difficult code. Of course, for one who is learning, todays difficult code is tomorrows preferred code.

Inheritance IS a core concept in OOP. But it is easily abused and/or applied improperly. Careful design of a class hierarchy is critical to proper use of the inheritance concept, and theree seem to most definitely be cases in which containment and delegation are prefferred ways to get things done.

But to say inheritance is useless is patently absurd.

For a good way to examine Interface/Base class/Inheritance modelling, look at the .net framework itself. From the object explorer one can examine the Inheritance model as it is applied to the core components we use every day.

Comment: Thanks XIVSolutions, another enlightening  answer.

Comment: In the choice between "because I can" and "because I need to", I would prefer a third option: "because I should"

Comment: @Phoog - Substitute "Because I should" for "Because I need to". Within my context, I guess I meant the same thing. There are places in which inheritance is the appropriate solution, and places where it is not. While I will grant that the MAY be some gray areas in between, I was addressing the idea that inheritance is often the seeming EASIER way to do something, which is not always the best or most appropriate way. In my veiw, "Because I can" is akin to using inheritance simply because its "neat", and so I want to use it. It is a great temptation for the newcomer. I know, 'cuz I did it!

Comment: I did too and I wholeheartedly support your position.  I just wanted to point out that inheritance can simplify code in cases where it may not be seen as "needed".  But "need" can mean different things to different people!

Answer (score 1):

In the average business case, no, you will not be creating deep hierarchies of types.  However, you *will* directly use inheritance ***all the time***.

Always.

An ASP.NET .aspx page with a code-behind *inherits* from your code-behind class.  Your code-behind class itself inherits from the Page class, and you override methods on it.  If you don't understand the meaning of override and virtual (both inheritance-related concepts), you are selling yourself short.

There are thousands of examples all over the framework where an understanding of inheritance and related concepts will help you organize your understanding of the objects you use on a daily basis.  Some of the best to really dig into relate to LINQ and Generics (IEnumerable, IQueryable, ICollection, etc), MVC / Web Forms, and Entity Framework and where you create POCO objects that relate to the business problem you are trying to solve.

The short answer is that you need to understand it, even if you are not writing a framework.  The passage from the book ([excerpt from page 72](http://books.google.com/books?id=KzsUd3ohSJkC&lpg=PP1&dq=Beginning%20ASP.NET%204%20in%20C%23%202010&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false)) is a little embarrassing in how blunt and misleading it is.

Comment: Think deeper - several of your examples are make the point: IEnumerable, IQueryable, ICollection, etc (that's not quite "inheritance").

Comment: @Mark - True.  I've added "inheritance and related concepts" to my text.

Comment: *Using* a framework designed with inheritance and understanding it's use are entirely different, IMO. The fact that an ASPX file inherits from a code-behind is irrelevant 99.9% of the time. To actually do anything with that knowledge also requires a fairly deep understanding of ASP.NET compilation and code generation - not quite fodder for a beginner's text. Inheriting from Page is also an irrelevant detail - the methods that you're likely to override have no base class implementation, and are really better suited to thinking of as event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

As I've worked on more and more code, I have come to similar conclusions (though not as provocative).  One reason is lack of multiple inheritance (which I now agree is a good thing), and the other is dependencies spiraling out of control.

These days I try to eschew inheritance and abstract classes and rely more on composition and interfaces (particularly now that extension methods can bridge the gap a bit to provide base method implementations to interfaces).

This leads to code that is much more reusable and testable, and much easier dependency management (using dependency inversion).

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly over-reacting objections of SO'ers aside, this is fairly common knowledge among object oriented programmers these days.

I disagree slightly with the precise word choice of the quote, but the sentiment is nothing more controversial than ["prefer composition over inheritance"](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=prefer%20compo&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=prefer%20composition%20over%20inheritance).

Specifically for [a book called "Beginning ASP.NET"](http://books.google.com/books?id=KzsUd3ohSJkC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=dan%20appleman%20inheritance%20%22the%20coolest%20feature%22%20never%20use&source=bl&ots=Ay6cqUBITS&sig=q6tWpxT8pPH3xTmo6Pj6pu3rcXI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VeeWT7rBFIWs8QTzycWVDg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dan%20appleman%20inheritance%20%22the%20coolest%20feature%22%20never%20use&f=false), I think it's pretty decent advice. The number of times you'll need to deal deeply with inheritance as a design mechanism in ASP.NET is pretty limited - especially as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There are many great answers already, however I had trouble understanding OOP while I was learning it myself, so this might help.

First just have a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619183556/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022001-1.shtml), it shows how you would use a class and then inheritance in a normal asp.net app.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) for a real world example of inheritance. Its the [Web Control class in asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx). It a class with common stuff for many controls, scroll down and see the **inheritance hierarchy** and see how many controls **inherit** from this control.

Comment: I don't THINK that Inheritance is useless, my question was clear.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to give you a real world example, I did say _"if"_ tho. I edited the question.